# In Boyer-Moore algorithm, why " if (bmGs[j] == m) " is necessary？

Tags: c++, algorithm

The code shows here: http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node14.html

And my question is in function `void preBmGs(char *x, int m, int bmGs[])`

For a good read, i paste the function below:

```
void preBmGs(char *x, int m, int bmGs[]) {
   int i, j, suff[XSIZE];

   suffixes(x, m, suff);

   for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
      bmGs[i] = m;
   j = 0;
   for (i = m - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (suff[i] == i + 1)
         for (; j < m - 1 - i; ++j)
            if (bmGs[j] == m)     //--here is my question, remove it, is ok ? --
               bmGs[j] = m - 1 - i;
   for (i = 0; i <= m - 2; ++i)
      bmGs[m - 1 - suff[i]] = m - 1 - i;
}
```

My reason is: `j` is incremental, so `j` certainly not go back.

I read many blogs about BM, but their code all contains the `if (bmGs[j] == m)`.

Comment: I can easily prove that the branch will evaluate to true.  What exactly confuses you, how it can be false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right. It doesn't make sense as bmGs[] is initialized to m for range of m and until the statement 
`if (bmGs[j] == m)` 
bmGs array is not modified. And there is no reason for checking with `bmGs[j] == m`

As it is going to be equal to m always for range of (m) and both the for loops are in valid range.

Comment: Also note `for (i = m - 1;` shoukd be `for (i = m - 2;` -- at `i=m-1` the loop can do nothing.  I suspect the code is written as easy to prove correct/understand more than optimally fast.